# Proving that a function has primitives

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, functions

Let f a differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$=$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$ .Prove that the function $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ admits primitives when g is:
$g(x)=f'(1/x)$, for any $x\neq 0$
and
$g(0)=0$
I tried to integrate the function g and to make the substitution $x:=1/x$ but it did not helped me out.

Comment: Any continuous function has a primitive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$H(x) = \begin{cases}x^2f(1/x),& x \neq 0\\0,& x= 0 \end{cases}$$

Since $\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$, it follows that $\lim_{x \to 0} xf(1/x) = 0$ and both $H$ and $x \mapsto H(x)/x$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Thus, a  primitive of $g$ is

$$G(x) = -H(x) + 2\int_0^x \frac{H(t)}{t} \, dt,$$

Note that for $x \neq 0$, we have

$$G'(x) = -H'(x) + 2\frac{H(x)}{x} = -2xf(1/x) +f'(1/x) + 2xf(1/x) = f'(1/x) = g(x) $$

Try to finish by showing that $G'(0) = g(0) = 0$.